# Button not working in HStack in Toolbar Navigation Bar SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, toolbar, hstack

I am trying to add a second line of buttons in my toolbar navigation view in SwiftUI so that it looks like this: [image: target UI] However, these bottom buttons lose their functionality. I put them in a HStack in the Toolbar.

This `HStack` is located in a `VStack` in a `ToolbarItemGroup` object. Does anyone know why these buttons do not notice when they are clicked?

The `ForEach` does not seem to be the problem because the button still does not work when it is just one of them. However, when it is placed outside of the `HStack`, it does work.

See code below:

`ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var searchQuery: String = ""
    @State var showNavigationBar = true
    @State var tabView: String = "home"
    @FocusState var searchInFocus: Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView(selection: $tabView) {
                Text("Hello World!")
                
            }.toolbar(showNavigationBar ? .visible : .hidden)
            .toolbar {
               
                    searchNav
                    
                }
        }.navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { newView in
                // destination view
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

`ToolbarItemGroup`:

```
extension ContentView {
    @ToolbarContentBuilder var searchNav: some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigation) {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    TextField("", text: $searchQuery, prompt: Text("Search Cleo.").foregroundColor(.black))
                        .focused($searchInFocus)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                    Button {
                        searchQuery = ""
                        tabView = "home"
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.black))
                            .imageScale(.large)
                            .frame(width: 50)
                            .frame(height: 40)
                            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7750167251, green: 0.8043509126, blue: 0.8005430698, alpha: 0.7539859694)))
                            .cornerRadius(25)
                        
                    }.padding(.top, 20)
                }
                
                
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<4) {buttonType in
                        Button {
                            print("clicked \(String(buttonType))")
                            // THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESN'T WORK
                        } label: {
                                Text(String(buttonType))
                        }
                    }  
                }.padding(.vertical)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Note that this code does not look nice on when rendered, yet it still highlights the main issue of the buttons not responding to clicks.

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) , including the NavigationView, toolbar, VStack, ToolbarItemGroup and any other relevant code that produces the problem you are having.

Comment: This is not a [mre]

Comment: @jnpdx Im sorry, I am fairly new to posting on Stack Overflow. Is it too much code or too little?

Comment: Did you read the link? The link explains what should be included. In short: it should be runnable by the person trying to help. Your code cannot be.

Comment: @jnpdx it should be reproducible now. Sorry about that

Comment: It looks like you're likely trying to stretch `ToolbarItemGroup` beyond what it's meant to do. My suspicion is that it starts misbehaving if the height is taller than the tab bar is supposed to be. Maybe someone else has a solution.